# iOS Mobile Device Management - The SCEP server returned an invalid response

Tags: ios, ruby, security, bouncycastle, mdm

I am in the process of writing an open source iOS mobile device management module in Java. For this I am referring the Apple provided Ruby code at [1]. I have set this up and it works fine for me. Now I need to convert this code to Java. So far I have accomplished to do that up to PKIOperation. In the PKI operation I get "The SCEP server returned an invalid response" which I believe is due to wrong response I sent to device upon PKIOperation.

However when I do search on the internet I get this is something to do with the "maxHttpHeaderSize" as I am using the server as Apache Tomcat. Although I increase that since still it does not get resolved.

Here is the code I need to convert - taken from Apple provided Ruby script

```
   if query['operation'] == "PKIOperation"
    p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new(req.body)
    store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
    p7sign.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
    signers = p7sign.signers
    p7enc = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new(p7sign.data)
    csr = p7enc.decrypt(@@ra_key, @@ra_cert)
    cert = issueCert(csr, 1)
    degenerate_pkcs7 = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new()
    degenerate_pkcs7.type="signed"
    degenerate_pkcs7.certificates=[cert]
    enc_cert = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt(p7sign.certificates, degenerate_pkcs7.to_der, 
        OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc"), OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    reply = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(@@ra_cert, @@ra_key, enc_cert.to_der, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    res['Content-Type'] = "application/x-pki-message"
    res.body = reply.to_der
   end
```

So this is how I written this in Java using Bouncycastle library.

```
        X509Certificate generatedCertificate = generateCertificateFromCSR(
                privateKeyCA, certRequest, certCA.getIssuerX500Principal()
                        .getName());

        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(
                generatedCertificate.getEncoded());
        CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator edGen = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
        edGen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(
                receivedCert).setProvider(AppConfigurations.PROVIDER));
        CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = edGen
                .generate(
                        msg,
                        new JceCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(
                                CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC).setProvider(
                                AppConfigurations.PROVIDER).build());

        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(
                AppConfigurations.SIGNATUREALGO).setProvider(
                AppConfigurations.PROVIDER).build(privateKeyRA);

        List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
        CMSTypedData cmsByteArray = new CMSProcessableByteArray(
                envelopedData.getEncoded());
        certList.add(certRA);

        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);

        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(
                        AppConfigurations.PROVIDER).build()).build(
                sha1Signer, certRA));

        gen.addCertificates(certs);

        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(cmsByteArray, true);

        return sigData.getEncoded();
```

The returned result here will be output in to the servlet output stream with the content type "application/x-pki-message".

It seems I get the CSR properly and I generate the X509Certificate using following code.

```
    public static X509Certificate generateCertificateFromCSR(
        PrivateKey privateKey, PKCS10CertificationRequest request,
        String issueSubject) throws Exception {

    Calendar targetDate1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    targetDate1.setTime(new Date());
    targetDate1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

    Calendar targetDate2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    targetDate2.setTime(new Date());
    targetDate2.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);

    // yesterday
    Date validityBeginDate = targetDate1.getTime();
    // in 2 years
    Date validityEndDate = targetDate2.getTime();

    X509v3CertificateBuilder certGen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(
            new X500Name(issueSubject), BigInteger.valueOf(System
                    .currentTimeMillis()), validityBeginDate,
            validityEndDate, request.getSubject(),
            request.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
    certGen.addExtension(X509Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(
            KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment));

    ContentSigner sigGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(
            AppConfigurations.SHA256_RSA).setProvider(
            AppConfigurations.PROVIDER).build(privateKey);

    X509Certificate issuedCert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
            .setProvider(AppConfigurations.PROVIDER).getCertificate(
                    certGen.build(sigGen));

    return issuedCert;
}
```

The generated certificate commonn name is,

Common Name: mdm(88094024-2372-4c9f-9c87-fa814011c525)

Issuer: mycompany Root CA (93a7d1a0-130b-42b8-bbd6-728f7c1837cf), None

[1] - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Im a total noob to ruby, could you please tell me how you set the apple code given in the document and made it work for you. Thanks. Also since you mention open source, i'd be grateful if you sent me a link to the java port, im a little lost on the documentation ruby code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts (not a real answer)

1) The "The SCEP server returned an invalid response" could be returned for a huge amount of different reasons. Generally speaking, if SCEP returns anything what can't be parsed by MDM client, it will show this error.

2) Take a look at jSCEP (https://code.google.com/p/jscep/). It's java implementation of SCEP server. And I am pretty sure that it works with iOS (I used it).

- You can both check how they are handling it (as I remember, they are using Bouncy Castle too)
- Also, I would rather include jSCEP in your open source imlpementation than reinvent a bycycle. SCEP RFC has quite a lot of pieces, jSCEP is pretty good with following it.

Comment: Thanks Victor. I already started looking at JSCEP. I believe it should work for my scenario.

Comment: For future references this worked fine for me. JSCEP does the PKIOperation part now. I was able to complete the MDM enrollment through Java. Thanks Victor. Accepting the answer.